# using findByPk with multiple id, error when pageSize more than 1 (yii)

Tags: php, sql, yii

it didn't show the names from findByPk i am using to view the names

here's the table i have:
table1(barang)
1.kode_barang(pk)
2.nama_barang

table2(transaksi)
1.kode_transaksi(pk)
2.kode_barang(fk)

,i set the controller to

```
         public function actionView($id)
    {
            $issueDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('detilTransaksi'/*nama file detilTransaksi.php*/, array('criteria'=>array('condition'=>'kode_transaksi=:kodeTransaksi',
                            'params'=>array(':kodeTransaksi'=>$this->loadModel($id)->kode_transaksi),
                    ),'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1,
                    ),
             ));
            $this->render('view',array(
                    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
                    'issueDataProvider'=>$issueDataProvider,
            ));



    }
```

`
then i set the _view.php to this :

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('no_transaksi')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->no_transaksi), array('detilTransaksi/view', 'id'=>$data->no_transaksi)); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('kode_transaksi')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->kode_transaksi); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('kode_barang')); ?>:</b>
<?php //echo CHtml::encode($data->kode_barang);
 $brg = Barang::model()->findByPK($data->kode_barang);
echo $brg->nama_barang; ?>
<br />
```

`

and this is 'view.php' to view the data

```
    <h1>View MasterTransaksi #<?php echo $model->kode_transaksi; ?></h1>

<? $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'kode_transaksi',
        'kode_konsumen',
        'kode_areaAsal',
        'kode_areaTujuan',
        'kode_areaPosisi',
        'nomor_kargo',
        'kode_armada',
        'tanggal_transaksi',
        'kode_operator',
    ),
)); 


//getting table 'barang'
     $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
     'dataProvider'=>$issueDataProvider,
     'itemView'=>'/detilTransaksi/_view',
     ));
```

all works and showing table1.nama_barang which i could get from findAllByPk(table2.id_barang),

but when i set the **pageSize bigger than 1**, it says 'Trying to get property of non-object',i have tried to use findAllByPk but it was provide the same error,

please help me to get the findByPk() work

'sorry for my bad english

i was implementing the example on yii books chapter 6 , 'listing the issues', 
here's the screenshots,
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--VNO9YLVAms/UvezBvfLAJI/AAAAAAAAA1A/JL2fv31DHN0/s1600/stackoverflow.jpg

i'm trying to view more than 1 'barang' perPages

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object", this message also contains the name of the non-object. Please post that part also, rather post full error so it may help to recognize the problem

Comment: i Got it, would be posted soon,

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if you use `findByPk()` if a record is found, the returned result will be a **single model**, BUT if you use `findAllByPk()` it will return **an array of models**!

so you have to use a loop on an array.

Comment: how to loop this array ?? ,please help i can't think of the right codes .